# Does frequently executing DDL affect the data synchronization speed in Syncer?

Tags: ddl, distributed-database, tidb

I am trying to import data incrementally into TiDB using the Syncer tool. I am wondering if I frequently execute DDL statements, will it affect the data synchronizing speed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. Syncer will first finish executing all the DML statements ahead, and then execute the DDL statements. And Syncer won’t start executing new DML statements until it finishes executing the DDL statements.